# How can I suppress the HTML 'HEAD' request from Excel

Tags: excel, http, https, excel-2016

I try to populate an Excel table with a  list of products with images of these products.

Apart from troubles to get the images to be displayed - which is solved - I got some images transfered and some not. Nevertheless all can be retrieved by browser(s).

I tracked the issue down to Excel which is not only sending a 'GET'-request to the server but upfront sends an '[OPTIONS](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.2)'- and an '[HEAD](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4)'-request. As this is not (yet) supported by most of the accessed servers (and not needed/wanted/requested :-( ) this results in an 'Method not supported' Error. Even as the file is in existance.

**My questions** is now, how can I disable these additional requests and just have the GET requests.

**Note:**

1. The sheet worked already about 3-4 weeks ago but seemed to have been 'destroyed' with one of the latest updates.
2. Problem exists with HTTP and HTTPS (does not make a difference)
3. by the way it's NOT a server-side issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285794/clicking-url-hyperlink-from-ms-excel-sends-a-http-head-request),

**Background:**

Excel 2016 , Win 7/64